# Produce Ultrasonic sound  of 8 kHz / 12 kHz / 15 kHz / 17.4 kHz / 22 kHz+iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to make the fly application
Like [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fly-and-mosquito-killer/id537160389?mt=8),
I know that i have to do coding such that it generate the ultrasonic sound which will keep the flies away to certain distance.And the sound which is not audible to human ears.

I dont have any idea regarding the ultrasonic sound in iphone.
Can any one please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download ultrasonic sound [here](http://www.ultrasonic-ringtones.com/) use according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i the application in whihc i want the ultrasound is on some HZ that human can not able to hear it.i.e sound is only audible to flies.so that they keep distance from that

Comment: download sounds from link i assume sounds from 12khz to 22khz we cannot hear

Answer (score 1):

iPhone is rated for a frequency response from 20Hz to 20,000Hz.

Ultrasonic sound is above 20,000Hz approximately, so I think it is not possible to do it (at least with the standard iphone speaker).

Comment: But there are many FLIES related application on appstore which are doing the same.So it rated response for iphone is above 20HZ then how some one had implemented that.

Comment: Maybe the speakers can reach the 22kHz (10% margin). Usually, commercial speakers are rated from 17Hz to 20KHz even the limit can be exceeded.